# How to get children values on antd's form submit?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I made a custom component called `TagsInput`, and added it to a form. My problem is, when the form is submitted, the value for field `tags` is always undefined, because the `Form.Item` cannot retrieve the value from the `TagsInput` child. This is usually not a problem when children of `Form.Item` are antd components.

```
export default function NewProjectForm(props) {
  return (
    <Form layout="vertical" onFinish={props.onSubmit} id="newProjectForm">   
      <Form.Item label="Tags" name="tags">
        <TagsInput />
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
}
```

`TagsInput` is a class component that has its value within its state:

```
class TagsInput extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            value: []
        }
    }

    render(){
        return(<div></div>)
    }
}
```

I dont want to elevate the value field from `TagsInput` state to `NewProjectForm` because it is not a class component... I would be doing it just for the sake of solving this issue. I am asking this question because I think there is a cleaner way of solving this.

How can I make `NewProjectForm` retrieve the value of `TagsInput` from within its state?
Is there any function I can pass to `TagsInput` as a property, so that the form asks the component for a value when it is submitted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achive what you want, you need to handle the state of the form (and its components) at the parent component (`NewProjectForm`).

If you are willing to keep that component a function component, you can use [React Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) and define a state with `useState` like this:

```
const [tagValue, setTagValue] = useState([]);
```

While `tagValue` is the value you will get from the child `TagsInput`, and the `setTagValue` is the function that can set that value. You need to pass `setTagValue` as a function prop to `TagsInput` and use it on change. It will look something like this:

```
export default function NewProjectForm(props) {

  const [tagValue, setTagValue] = useState([]);

  return (
    <Form layout="vertical" onFinish={props.onSubmit} id="newProjectForm">   
      <Form.Item label="Tags" name="tags">
        <TagsInput setTagValue={(val)=>setTagValue(val)} />
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
}

class TagsInput extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            value: []
        }
    }

    ......... 
    ......... 
    onChangeInput(val){
        this.props.setTagValue(val);
    }
    ......... 
    ......... 

    render(){
        return(<div></div>)
    }
}
```

### EDIT

After the clarification in the comments, you actually need to follow the steps of using `Customized Form Controls`, As described [here](https://ant.design/components/form/#components-form-demo-customized-form-controls).

You need to pass an object with `value` and `onChange` that changes the value. Then, the Form component should manage to get that value automatically.

So I guess it should look something like that:

```
const TagsInput= ({ value = {}, onChange }) => {

  const triggerChange = newValue => {
    if (onChange) {
      onChange(newValue);
    }
  };

  return(<div></div>)

};
```

Comment: Thank you for the response @SomoKRoceS. So, essentially, this is lifting the state up to the parent component. How does antd do with its own components? I dont need the `Input` state on the parent component to have the form access its value on the submission...

Comment: Oh ok I got it now.. well, you actually need to follow the steps of using `Customized Form Controls`, As described [here](https://ant.design/components/form/#components-form-demo-customized-form-controls). You need to pass an object with `value` and `onChange` that changes the value. Then, the `Form` component should manage to get that value automatically. I'm editing the answer.

Comment: Works like a charm. In fact, Antd passes `value` and `onChange` by default to children of `Form.Item`. We can use that API to communicate with the parent's (`Form.Item` in this case) state. Thank you for the response.